# Quasi 1D insulators with strong spin-orbital interaction

Tags: experimental-physics, condensed-matter, research-level, topological-order

We know that the spin-1 chain realizes [the Haldane phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKLT_Model) which is an example of
symmetry protected topological (SPT) phases (ie short-range entangled phases with symmetry). The Haldane phase is protected by the $SO(3)$ spin rotation symmetry.
If we change the symmetry, we may obtain [other possible SPT phases](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5162). 
This motivates us to ask the following question:

**What are good material examples of quasi 1D insulators with strong spin-orbital interaction?**

There are large $U$ Mott insulators and there are small $U$ band insulators. Here, we are interested in both, and like to see examples for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

I can provide an example for bosonic models.

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{H} & = & \mathcal{K} + \mathcal{T}_\text{soc}
                  +\frac{U}{2}\sum_{i\tau} \hat n_{i\tau}( \hat n_{i\tau}-1) \nonumber \\
            &   & + U^{\prime} \sum_i \hat n_{i\uparrow} \hat n_{i\downarrow} + V\sum_{i\tau} \hat{n}_{i\tau}\hat{n}_{i+1\tau} \nonumber \\
            &   & +V^\prime\sum_{i\tau} \hat{n}_{i\tau} \hat{n}_{i+1\bar{\tau}} -\mu\sum_{i}\hat n_{i},
\label{HSOC}
\end{eqnarray}
where 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{T}_\text{soc} = -\lambda\sum_i(\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\uparrow}\hat{c}_{i+1\downarrow} -\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\downarrow}\hat{c}_{i+1\uparrow})+h.c.,
\end{equation}
is the spin-orbit coupling, $\mathcal{K}$
is the hopping term.

Comment: Which materials realize the above model?